For a proper scheme $X,$ the neutral component of automorphism group scheme $\mathrm{Aut}^0_X$ is an algebraic group
I am currently reading through M. Brion's "Notes on Automorphism Groups of Projective Varieties" found here. On page 5 he writes

We assume from now on that $X$ is proper, and we denote by $\mathrm{Aut}_X$ its automorphism group scheme; then we have $\mathrm{Aut}_X(S) = \mathrm{Aut}(X \times S/S)$ for any scheme $S.$ Since $\mathrm{Aut}_X$ is a locally algebraic group, it has a largest closed connected normal subgroup scheme: the neutral component, that we denote by $\mathrm{Aut}^0_X$ . Moreover, $\mathrm{Aut}^0_X$ is an algebraic group...

To Brion's credit, he does give a reference. Namely, M. Demazure, P. Gabriel, "Groupes algébriques" but unfortunately I do not read French.
I would like to understand, in particular, why $\mathrm{Aut}^0_X$ is an algebraic group. An English reference would be helpful too

It looks to me as if Brion defines the subgroup $\operatorname{Aut}^0_X$ to be Zariski closed, so algebraic.

good question, upvoted

The existence (plus basic properties) of the group $Aut^0$ can be found here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B7R  (in a more general context). Note that $\mathrm{Aut}_{X}$  is a priori only a locally finite type group scheme. However, as $\mathrm{Aut}_X^0$ is quasi-compact (see link above), it is a finite type group scheme, hence "algebraic group" (depending on your definition of "algebraic group" you might have to appeal to some other standard properties of finite type group schemes, e.g., such schemes are automatically separated and even quasi-projective).
